# Authenticate to Github from an AzureDevOps GitHub-InstallationToken service connection

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, github-api

Azure DevOps online. I have a GitHub service connection of type "GitHub-InstallationToken". I'm trying to use this endpoint to authenticate to GitHub from a custom release task.

Unlike legacy Github endpoints, the endpoint object's auth parameters object doesn't contain an `accessToken`, instead it contains `IdToken` and `IdSignature`. I suspect I need to either make a JWT out of those, or exchange those for a short lived token, but how?

Preferably with no dependencies other than a basic REST client (currently using Axios).

UPD: `IdToken` looks like a large integer number. `IdSignature` is a JWT. If one looks inside said JWT, it has
`{"typ":"JWT","alg":"HS256"}` for header and `{"installationId":"11111111", "iss":"vsts", "aud":"vsts", "nbf":-62135593139, "exp":-62135593139}` for claims. The value of `installationId` matches the value of `IdToken`.

I immediately thought that those were the arguments to POST `https://api.github.com/app/installations/{IdToken}/access_tokens`, but got back error 401 with error message "'Expiration time' claim ('exp') must be a numeric value representing the future time at which the assertion expires".

And that makes sense. What's the deal with negative `nbf` and `exp`? They correspond to Jan 12, 1968 8:06:47 PM in UTC. Normally, JWTs are timed, current, and relatively short lived. That said, the parameters on a service endpoint can't, to the best of my knowledge, be dynamically generated. Or can they? To get to the endpoint auth parameters, I use:

```
const tl = require("azure-pipelines-task-lib/task");
const auth = tl.getEndpointAuthorization(tl.getInput("EndpointParameterName"), false).parameters;
```

EDIT: somewhat known (to Microsoft) issue: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9394 . No fix in sight. Also https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/18413 .

So *officially*, using this endpoint in custom tasks is not a supported scenario. However, if you create a build pipeline with sources in Github and that endpoint as auth, it works. Ergo, the built-in "get the sources" logic authenticates somehow.

EDIT: Fiddler suggests that the build job does not talk to Github directly. Instead, I can see it issues a POST to `/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery/project/877e6ad3-702d-48ea-89c7-e01f44ce382` passing a JSON where there is a contributionId for `ms.vss-build-web.git-branch-data-provider`. If I'm reading the tea leaves right, Github access is somehow proxied through Azure DevOps server. That might genuinely preclude the client-only usage of that endpoint.

Why do they expose those crippled parameters in the endpoint data anyway is anybody's guess.

FYI, Microsoft's own "Github Comment" task doesn't accept this kind of endpoint, either.